# Pandas read_csv drops first 2 digits from year

Tags: pandas, python-datetime

In my .csv file I have a datetime column in a `05/20/1935 12:00:00 AM` format. Whenever I inject the data to pandas, the format changes to `5-20-35 12:00` and this would later on ruin my calculations as `pd.to_datetime()` would convert it to be `2035`.

**EDIT**

if I have the following `csv_file
id, birthday
0, 10/21/1967  12:00:00 AM
1, 01/10/1962  12:00:00 AM
2, 22/12/1983  12:00:00 AM`

and use 
`df = pd.read_csv('csv_file')`

I get the following output
`df
id | birthday
0  | 10/21/67 0:00
1  | 1/10/62  0:00
2  | 22/12/83 0:00`

Note: I cannot explicitly mention that the date is in the 19xx because some dates are in 20xx.

Comment: There are a number of ways to parse dates using read_csv: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html . Please post the full syntax for your read_csv command so we know which of them you're using. If I try with that date and read_csv with all default parameters it parses correctly.

Comment: I used default parameters but I still seem to lose some information.

Comment: With the additional data I notice you have a mixture of MM/DD/YYYY and DD/MM/YYYY dates. As long as one of them is greater than 12 you can unambiguously recognize the format, but you won't know whether 01/10/1962 is January 10 or October 1 if you have mixed formats like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a `|sv` file as opposed to a `csv` file.  Try the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', sep='|', index_col=0)
```

Comment: Apologies, the `|` was just to structure the question, it's actually a `.csv` file.

Comment: Ok.  What version of `python` and `pandas` are you using?

Comment: python version `3.6.3` and pandas version `0.20.3`

Comment: perhaps you could try updating `pandas` which is currently at `v0.23.4`; I am not getting the same issue as you are indicating.

Comment: I looked further into it, and it does seem like the problem is from Microsoft excel. It's appears as it's a four digit number but only saves two. Thanks for the help!